# CTE Aggregation by 2 Different Date Periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, common-table-expression

I have the following sample data and desired output, the SQL query I have written doesn't quite yield the results I am looking for and I can't understand why. I have tried different groupings, aggregating or non-aggregating the Units column, nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Data:

EarnedQ:

| ActivityID | EarnedMH_I | Period_WE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CS0001 | 206.79 | 5/27/2023 |
| CS0001 | 41.35 | 6/10/2023 |

PlannedQ:

| ActivityID | EarnedMH_I | Period_WE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CS0001 | 41.36 | 5/20/2023 |
| CS0001 | 41.36 | 5/27/2023 |
| CS0001 | 33.09 | 6/03/2023 |
| CS0001 | 41.36 | 6/10/2023 |

PeriodQ:

| Weekending | Period_WE |
| --- | --- |
| 5/20/2023 | 5/27/2023 |
| 5/27/2023 | 5/27/2023 |
| 6/03/2023 | 6/10/2023 |
| 6/10/2023 | 6/10/2023 |

SQL I have tried:

```
WITH AggregatedEarnedHours AS (
    SELECT
        WBS,
        ActivityID,
        Period_WE,
        SUM(EarnedMH_I) AS EarnedHours
    FROM
        EarnedQ
    GROUP BY
        WBS,
        ActivityID,
        Period_WE
),
AggregatedPlannedHours AS (
    SELECT
        AID,
        EOW2 AS Period_WE,
        SUM(Units) AS PlannedHours
    FROM 
        PlannedQ T
        JOIN PeriodQ P ON T.Weekending = P.Period_WE
    GROUP BY
        AID,
        EOW2
)
SELECT
    E.WBS,
    E.ActivityID,
    E.Period_WE,
    SUM(E.EarnedHours) AS EarnedHours,
    ISNULL(P.PlannedHours, 0) AS PlannedHours
FROM 
    AggregatedEarnedHours E
LEFT JOIN AggregatedPlannedHours P ON E.ActivityID = P.AID AND E.Period_WE = P.Period_WE
GROUP BY 
    E.WBS,
    E.ActivityID,
    E.Period_WE,
    P.PlannedHours
HAVING (SUM(E.EarnedHours) != 0 OR SUM(P.PlannedHours) !=0) AND 
    SUM(E.EarnedHours) > 0
```

Current Output:

| ActivityID | EarnedMH_I | Units | WeekEnding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CS0001 | 206.79 | 579.04 | 5/27/2023 |
| CS0001 | 41.35 | 521.15 | 6/10/2023 |

Desired Output:

| ActivityID | EarnedMH_I | Units | WeekEnding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CS0001 | 206.79 | 82.72 | 5/27/2023 |
| CS0001 | 41.35 | 74.45 | 6/10/2023 |

As you can see it almost works, but the planned hours are too high. I have a feeling it has to do with doing the aggregation or grouping incorrectly. Also, this data is abbreviated for sake of posting, there are more rows in all the tables but you get the idea. Note that PlannedQ is weekly data whereas I am trying to group biweekly here. A manual grouping by biweekly will not fit my solution, as I need to group by monthly in other cases too and need something dynamic, hence the inclusion of the PeriodQ table.

Comment: A DBFiddle would make it much easier to have a play around with your data

Comment: Your sample data won't produce the same issue. But just looking at your query, your actual outcome is 7x your desired outcome, so my guess is either you've got 7 duplicates in PlannedQ for a given AID/EOW2 or there are 7 duplicate Period_WE rows in PeriodQ... I'd try to figure out where the 7x is coming from because it's one of those 2 tables. You either need stricter join conditions or you need to eliminate the duplicates some other way.

Comment: @ZLK you are absolutely correct, can't believe I didn't notice that 7 factor. I have a feeling it is my dates table. I will do some testing and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE EarnedQ(
   ActivityID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
  ,EarnedMH_I NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
  ,Period_WE  DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO EarnedQ
(ActivityID,EarnedMH_I,Period_WE) VALUES 
('CS0001',206.79,'5/27/2023'),
('CS0001',41.35,'6/10/2023');
---------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE PlannedQ(
   ActivityID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
  ,EarnedMH_I NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL
  ,Period_WE  DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO PlannedQ
(ActivityID,EarnedMH_I,Period_WE) VALUES 
('CS0001',41.36,'5/20/2023'),
('CS0001',41.36,'5/27/2023'),
('CS0001',33.09,'6/03/2023'),
('CS0001',41.36,'6/10/2023');
------------------------
CREATE TABLE PeriodQ(
   Weekending DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Period_WE  DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO PeriodQ
(Weekending,Period_WE) VALUES 
('5/20/2023','5/27/2023'),
('5/27/2023','5/27/2023'),
('6/03/2023','6/10/2023'),
('6/10/2023','6/10/2023');
```

use Subquery to get your desired result

```
SELECT A.ActivityID,EarnedMH_I,Units,Weekending
FROM 
(select E.ActivityID,E.EarnedMH_I ,PE.Weekending
from EarnedQ E
JOIN PeriodQ PE
ON E.Period_WE=PE.Weekending 
AND E.Period_WE BETWEEN PE.Weekending AND  PE.Period_WE 
  ) A
JOIN 
(
select P.ActivityID,SUM(P.EarnedMH_I) Units,PE1.Period_WE
from PlannedQ P
JOIN PeriodQ PE1
ON P.Period_WE=PE1.Weekending AND 
P.Period_WE BETWEEN PE1.Weekending AND  PE1.Period_WE
GROUP BY P.ActivityID,PE1.Period_WE
) B
ON A.ActivityID=B.ActivityID AND Period_WE=Weekending
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NiE1jsGf)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ZLK for pointing out where my error was, and thanks RF1991 for the code. I had 7 dates per Weekending, choosing a different column to join on (Period instead of Period_WE) which only has 1 date per Weekending was the solution. SQL below:

```
SELECT A.ActivityID,EarnedMH_I,Units,Weekending
FROM 
(select E.ActivityID,E.EarnedMH_I ,PE.Period
from EarnedQ E
JOIN PeriodQ PE
ON E.Period_WE=PE.Period
AND E.Period_WE BETWEEN PE.Weekending AND  PE.Period
  ) A
JOIN 
(
select P.ActivityID,SUM(P.EarnedMH_I) Units,PE1.Period
from PlannedQ P
JOIN PeriodQ PE1
ON P.Period =PE1.Weekending AND 
P.Period_WE BETWEEN PE1.Weekending AND PE1.Period
GROUP BY P.ActivityID,PE1.Period
) B
ON A.ActivityID=B.ActivityID AND Period =Weekending
```